# Chrome developer tool erroneously interpreting console log string output as links

Tags: string, hyperlink, google-chrome-devtools, console.log, interpretation

When you use console.log to display a string, Chrome will interpret certain portions of the string as links, and decorate the console output accordingly. How can that be prevented? Here is a sample that demonstrates the issue. Notice that although there are no links in the output of the second console.log statement, Chrome still interprets a portion of it as a hyperlink.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<p id="jedi_mind_trick">This is not the demo you are looking for. Move along!</p>

</body>
<script>
function example() {
  var test = {data:$('#jedi_mind_trick').html(),obi_wan:"kenobi"};
}
console.log(typeof example, example);
console.log(typeof example.toString(), example.toString());
</script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else who might be experiencing this problem, I have discovered a workaround that avoids the developer console's log output link decoration feature. Simply use the chrome devtools copy command to copy the raw output to the clipboard as follows

```
copy(example.toString());
```